# Connect to RDS eb2 by tableplus?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have [table plus](https://tableplus.com/) app and I create `eb` then deploy my project then connect to database and all thing is good and cool!

I need to connect to database(MYSQL) to import some data to the AWS database so I do these steps:

1. open new workspace in table plus
2. take `endpoint` and `username` of database and the `password` and the `name of database` like so:

[image]

1. press Test button and after wait some times I got this error:

[image]

> I change the port to also 5432 and got same first error

4. I change the port to 3306 and got this error:

[image]

where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is that the configuration you created is set to a Redshift connection. It expects some network communications that are different from a MySQL connection.

Can you try to create a MySQL connection instead?

Answer (score 4):

Ok the way i did it was by following this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saX75fTwh0M&ab_channel=AdobeinaMinute

In short you need to get the details of your instance and set up an ssh connection to it using its hostname (ie that of the instance not the db), your ec2 username (usually ec2-user) and your pem file. Then you get the connection details for the db and enter them. See the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What does connecting to an RDS database have to do with an EC2 instance or user name? What is a pem file?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but my problem was with the security rules in aws. perhaps, this may help.

- Navigate to the console
- edit inbound rules of your rds instance
- add a new security rule
- where: **type**: 'all traffic', **source**: anywhere
  This video gives a google explanation: [aws rds setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ng_zi11N4_c&t=359s)